Etymology of ガン詰め
I am not sure what is the origin of the word ガン詰め. Google search tells me that it means 徹底的に追求すること but I cannot find it in any known dictionary (?).
My guess is that the ガン part means an eye (眼) and 詰め is just 詰める. I assume that ガン詰め comes from 眼を詰めること. I am not sure what is the exact meaning of 詰める but I think it means to pack something in...
Any ideas?

"but I cannot find it in any known dictionary" - where did you find it originally?

@KarlKnechtel It is from one of the mangas I was reading.

詰めるは デジタル大辞泉 でいう 「７ 相手にきびしくせまる。追い込む。追い詰める。」で，「ガン」は多分「ガン無視」とかに共通してガンガンから来てるんじゃないかと思いますが，ガンが何から来てるかについては明確な根拠はありません

This ガン is a slang prefix that roughly means "intensively" or "entirely". Other slang words that start with ガン include:

ガン見(する)
ガン無視(する)
ガンギレ(する)
ガン泣き(する)
ガンギマリ

ガン詰め is less common than these, but it's easily understandable.
If I remember correctly, such ガン-words were popular among young people around 2000, and some of them are still actively in use in slang speech. The origin is not well understood, but people on the net suggest that it's probably related to either the onomatopoeia ガンガン or the kanji 頑 (as in 頑として). It has nothing to do with 眼.
